# enums exceeding the size of the largest number type

Tags: c++, enums

I want to fully understand how a C++ compiler deals with an enum exceeding the largest possible number, i.e., containing `-1` and `UINT64_MAX` the at the same time, i.e.

```
enum A {
    X = -1,
    Y = UINT64_MAX
};
```

First I thought that a compiler won't accept this code. Actually it doesn't compile when `enum`is replaced by `enum class`, but the above example compiles. According to the standard we have for the underlying type:

> Declares an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (in this case, the underlying type is an implementation-defined integral type that can represent all enumerator values; this type is not larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0). (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

But what means this for my example?

I wrote a small sample program to find out what happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

enum A {
    X = -1,
    XX = -1,
    Y = UINT64_MAX
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "X unsigned: " << (uint64_t)(X) << ", signed: " << (int64_t)(X) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y unsigned: " << (uint64_t)(Y) << ", signed: " << (int64_t)(Y) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(X == XX) == " << (X == XX) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(X == Y) == " << (X == Y) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
X unsigned: 18446744073709551615, signed: -1
Y unsigned: 18446744073709551615, signed: -1
(X == XX) == 1
(X == Y) == 0
```

Now I am quite confused. Obviously, X and Y represent the same number, but they are still distinguishable, i.e., the comparison `X == Y` is false (but `X=XX` is actually true). What happens here?

I know, the better way is not use the old `enum`, but the new `enum class`.
But still `enum` is widely used and I want to understand what happens here.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?

Comment: @melpomene `C` has no `enum class` so I think it's safe to assume that we're dealing with `C++` only. Even the tag matches it. The title seems to be simply an oversight.

Comment: @melpomene looking at the tags it's C++ usage of C-style `enum` (as opposed to `enum class`)

Comment: Its not reproducible: https://ideone.com/zTP38z

Comment: It's a C++ project, hence I use a C++ compiler. I personally would prefer `enum class`, but still `enum` is used many times in the project....

Comment: I've removed all references to C from the title / question.

Comment: What is `sizeof(A)` on your platform? 64 bit is not necessarily the largest integer type on every platform.

Comment: It is reproducable with gcc: https://ideone.com/bh1iud

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your compiler is most likely using a 128 bit signed integral type as the backing type, in concurrence with the C++ standard.

See for yourself with

```
std::cout << sizeof(std::underlying_type<A>::type);
```

Link: https://ideone.com/z4K0rz, outputs 16.

The output you observe is consistent with a narrowing conversion of this to a 64 bit unsigned type.

Comment: Huh - wanted to write a joke comment for this - now turns out it is the truth... Too bad standardisation team did not define (u)int128_t right together with the other ones - or add at least, when 64 bit systems got widely spread around the world...

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing is an effect of the type-casting and not the `enum`. Your output depends on how you cast the value.

Try this: It has the same output as yours, without the `enum`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "X unsigned: " << (uint64_t)(-1) << ", signed: " << (int64_t)(-1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
X unsigned: 18446744073709551615, signed: -1
```

Comment: The question is about enums though. All your example does is print the same thing  twice, nothing but the letter in the text is different, so of course they will produce the same results. If I copy/paste a line of code I'd expect the second to do the same as the first.

Comment: While there's some truth in for the casts, it does not explain the more important part of the question how X can be unequal to Y...

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Yes, indeed. The question is titled *enums exceeding the size of the largest number type*. I removed the redundant line. The OP asked and I quote, `Obviously, X and Y represent the same number, but they are still distinguishable, ...`. The **only** difference that the OP shows in his output is only a result of how he casts.